# Numpy mean with condition

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have algorithm of calculating average speed in pure python:

```
speed = [...]
avg_speed = 0.0
speed_count = 0

for i in speed:
    if i > 0: # I dont need zeros
        avg_speed += i
        speed_count += 1

if speed_count == 0:
    return 0.0

return avg_speed / speed_count
```

Is there any way to rewrite this functions with Numpy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def avg_positive_speed(speed):
    s = np.array(speed)
    positives = s > 0
    if positives.any():
        return s[positives].mean()
    else:
        return 0.


speed = [1., 2., 0., 3.]
print avg_positive_speed(speed)
# prints 2.0

print avg_positive_speed([0., 0.])
# prints 0.0
```

Answer (score 31):

I'm surprised no one has suggested the shortest solution:

```
speeds_np = np.array(speeds)

speeds_np[speeds_np>0].mean()
```

**Explanation:**

`speedsNp > 0` creates a boolean array of the same size satisfying the (in)equality. If fed into `speedsNp`, it yields only the corresponding values of `speedNp` where the value of the boolean array is `True`. All you need to do then, is just take the `mean()` of the result.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer here. Thanks @TimY

Comment: Agreed. This is a very clean solution. If you want to add multiple conditions, it's also really easy in this format: `speeds_np[(speeds_np>0) & (speeds_np<100)].mean()`

Answer (score 28):

The function `numpy.average` can receive a `weights` argument, where you can put a boolean array generated from some condition applied to the array itself - in this case, an element being greater than 0:

```
average_speed = numpy.average(speeds, weights=(speeds > 0))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This has the advantage of working if you want to use the `axis` argument of `np.average`.

Answer (score 3):

I know you want a `numpy` solution, so this doesn't meet that criteria (@eumiro's earlier post certainly does), but just as an alternative, here's an optimized Python version which surprisingly (to me at least) turned out to be quite speedy!

```
speeds = [i for i in speed if i > 0]
return  sum(speeds) / (1.0 * len(speeds)) if sum(speeds) > 0 else 0.0
```

Might be interesting to compare this with the numpy (or the original) implementation in terms of speed.

```
In [14]: timeit original(speed)              # original code
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop

In [15]: timeit python_opt(speed)            # above Python 2 liner
1000 loops, best of 3: 582 us per loop

In [16]: timeit avg_positive_speed(speed)    # numpy code
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 ms per loop
```

where

```
speed = range(10000)
```

I would have thought that `numpy` would have the edge here .. anyone know why it trails?

Update:

with `speed = range(100000)`:

```
In [19]: timeit original(speed)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

In [20]: timeit python_opt(speed)
100 loops, best of 3: 11 ms per loop

In [21]: timeit avg_positive_speed(speed)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 ms per loop
```

Still not convinced that `numpy` is a good tool for ***this*** particular problem, unless there are a **huge** number of speeds :)

How does numpy handle memory? list comprehension will at some point bump into some limitations.

Comment: Try larger numbers.  With 1000, the conversion from a list to an array is dominating the timings.

Comment: @JoeKington just doing this now .. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that conversion of a large list to a numpy array is a relatively slow process. If the data is already a numpy array (which uses _far_ less memory than a list) then the numpy versions will be much faster. Otherwise, you won't see a large difference for a single operation, as most of the time will be eaten up converting the list to an array.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks Joe, I was wondering about some initial overhead for numpy.

Answer (score 3):

As of [v1.20](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html#where-keyword-argument-for-numpy-functions-mean-std-var) numpy's `mean` etc functions support a `where` argument:

```py
speed.mean(where=speed>0)
```