# Vectorized numpy mean with condition

Tags: python, numpy

Similar to [Numpy mean with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084710/numpy-mean-with-condition)
My question extends it to operate on a matrix:  Compute the row means of matrix rdat, skipping certain cells -- I'm using 0 in this example as the cell to skip -- as if these values were never present in the first place. For example row index 1 of the following matrix has just 2 entries so the mean of [4,0,0,1] equals 5/2 not 5/4:

```
rdat = np.array([
    [5.,3.,0.,1.],
    [4.,0.,0.,1.],
    [1.,1.,0.,5.],
    [1.,0.,0.,4.],
    [0.,1.,5.,4.]
    ],dtype=np.float32)
```

The goal is to vectorize the computation, which is to say, no loops allowed.

The following code will compute row means of matrix rdat, one row at a time. Correct results are produced, but code is not vectorized yet:

```
u = np.zeros((5,1))
for i in range(5):
    u[i,0] = rdat[i][rdat[i]>0].mean()
print(u)
```

What was tried already:

```
I = 5; J = 4
# Try with numpy to develop syntax for user_bias for tf.
mrdat = np.matrix(rdat)
keep = mrdat > 0
print(keep)

keepr,keepc = np.where(keep)
print(keepr)
print(keepc)
#np.mean(rdat[keepr,keepc], 1)

#(keepr,keepc) = np.where(keep)
#np.mean(rdat[keepr,keepc], 1)

#keepidx = zip(np.where(keep))
#np.mean(rdat[keepidx], 1)

#rdat[keepr, keepc]
#rdat[keepr]
#np.mean(rdat[keepr], 1)

#rdat[0,keep].mean()
#rdat[keep[0]].mean()
#rdat[0,keep[0,:]]
print(keep[0])
x0 = np.ravel(keep[0])
print("flatnonzero: {}".format(np.flatnonzero(mrdat)))
print(x0)
#keepr
#rdat[keep[0]]

x = rdat[0]
print("x:{}".format(x))
x[x>0].mean() #OK
rdat[0][rdat[0]>0].mean() #OK output for single row
print(rdat[:][rdat[:]>0].mean()) # wrong output for each row
```

Have fun and thanks for reading.

Comment: `rdat.sum(1)/(rdat!=0).sum(1)`?

Comment: @Divakar It's good. Why not post as answer and get credit my dude?

Comment: You have a float array; make sure you're not bitten by floating-point errors later.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy mean with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790465/9067615)

Answer (score 2):

Simply get the count of non-zeros and divide by the summations -

```
from __future__ import division

def meanNA(a, NA, axis):
    mask = a!=NA
    return (a*mask).sum(axis=axis)/mask.sum(axis=axis)
```

Replace `(a*mask).sum(axis=axis)` with `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,mask)` for the specific case of 2D arrays with reduction along the second axis to get performance boost.

Sample run -

```
In [21]: rdat
Out[21]: 
array([[5., 3., 0., 1.],
       [4., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 5.],
       [1., 0., 0., 4.],
       [0., 1., 5., 4.]], dtype=float32)

In [22]: meanNA(rdat, NA=0, axis=1) # mean along each row skipping 0s
Out[22]: array([3.        , 2.5       , 2.33333333, 2.5       , 3.33333333])

In [23]: meanNA(rdat, NA=0, axis=0) # mean along each col skipping 0s
Out[23]: array([2.75      , 1.66666667, 5.        , 3.        ])

In [24]: meanNA(rdat, NA=3, axis=1) # mean along each row skipping 3s
Out[24]: array([2.  , 1.25, 1.75, 1.25, 2.5 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
rdat[rdat==0]=np.nan
np.nanmean(rdat, axis=1)
```